# Php web link href

Tags: php, database, href

I have made this code, and it works good, but I need how to create an link(href) on the output file. 
I tried several ways but i just cant, don't need an answer but some pointers where to learn.

```
 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $output =  $row["id"];
 }
 if ($output) {
     echo $output; 
 }
 else { 
     echo "That is not a valid record on our database";
 }
```

Comment: Try showing what you have tried and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I tried to make something like this: <a href=/songs.php?id=".$output.">Click here</a>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just echo the anchor tag with your `$output`

```
$output =  $row["title"];
$output ='FirstSong'; #To test i am using this as FirstSong
echo "<a href='songs?id=".$output."'>Click here</a>"; #You can have any text for href
```

So your code will be

```
 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $output =  $row["title"];
 }
 if ($output) { 
 echo "<a href='songs?id=".$output."'>Click here</a>";
 }
 else { echo "That is not a valid record on our database"; }
```

Here is the [demo](http://codepad.org/LV81craL)

Comment: Both your links cease to exist in *"You can the code and the output"*. Please remove them from your answer.

Comment: You edited it, great and thanks, but http://runnable.com/me/VSGTb8BYLZ9DjMFh that doesn't exist neither also. I'm wondering if the service you are using, only keeps those for a certain period of time.

Comment: @Fred-ii Thanks for reminding , the service i chose exists only for few hours in server (just now i know it) and i have updated the link to [codepad](http://www.codepad.org) Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome Sulthan; and thanks for the new update, *cheers*